# virtual keyboard pops up,when usb barcode scans

Tags: flutter

At the starting time, bar code scans perfectly. When i click on a textfield and done the work on it and cancel the focus on textfield. After that, when i scan the barcode using usb barcode scanner, the keyboard pops up. Can anyone help with this situation.